# How to give custom menu access/permissions to a role?

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a new custom menu in backend. Now I want to select this new menu in order to give permissions (or not) to the roles that I have on my website. The problem is that this new custom menu doesn't appears in the resources of the role. You can see this menu only if you have all the access granted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <pump_orders translate="title" module="pump_orders">
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <title>Orders - Pump</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/order/</action>
                </pump_orders>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set this in your `config.xml` or in `adminhtml.xml`, whichever best for you.

```
<acl><!-- permits -->
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <sales>
                   <children>
                       <pump_orders translate="title" module="pump_orders">
                          <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                          <title>Orders - Pump</title>
                      </pump_orders>
                  </children>
                </sales>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

This should make your menu item available in "permission" section, where you can set for different users.

Please read this article - [Alan Storm has described here](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration).